# How to delete all docker images matching a filter (project name) aside the 3(n) last ones?

Tags: docker

I have a simple CI sort of system.

I will explain in details with one example what I do and what I want to delete.

I upload my `d_api` project into AWS ECR repository `secret.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/d_api` always with different tags matching the git commit

I build and push those images from my CI machine to AWS ECR.

The moment an image is successfully pushed I want to delete the previous images BUT KEEP THE LAST 2 ones for this project (including the one I just pushed, so 3 in total).

**What I tried so far?**

I can filter the images by the reference like this

```
docker image ls --filter 'reference=secret.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/d_api*'
```

The result will show all the images for this particular project.

I want to delete all but the last 3.

To do that I am trying to use the `docker image prune` command but can't seem to find the correct filter.

I can use time-based filters fine `docker image prune -af --filter "until=720h"` but they are not needed in my case. I want to delete all but last 3.

Is such a thing possible ?

If that is not possible, how can I modify my time filter and delete "all images of api repository older than 30 days".

I believe doing this should work

```
docker image prune -af --filter "reference=secret.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/d_api* until=720h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having:

```bash
$ docker pull busybox
$ docker tag busybox busybox:1
$ docker tag busybox busybox:2
$ docker tag busybox busybox:3
$ docker tag busybox busybox:4

$ docker images ls --filter 'reference=busybox'
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
busybox      1         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      2         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      3         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      4         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      latest    a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
```

then to delete all but the last 3 (using bash):

```bash
$ docker images ls --filter 'reference=busybox' | head -n -3 | awk 'NR>1{print $1 ":" $2'} | xargs -I {} docker image rm {}
Untagged: busybox:1
Untagged: busybox:2

$ docker images ls --filter 'reference=busybox'
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
busybox      3         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      4         a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
busybox      latest    a416a98b71e2   8 weeks ago   4.26MB
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. Will test it on mac arm 64 now`/bin/bash`